# Передача указателя с nullptr в функцию и перевыделение памяти на него

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, ссылки, передача-параметров

Нужно загрузить указатель, который указывает на nullptr в функцию и выделить память с nullptr на новый не пустой участок памяти так, чтоб при выходе из функции загруженный указатель изменился

```cpp
void foo(int *p) {
    delete p;
    p = new int(643);
}

int main() {
    int *a = nullptr;
    foo(a);
    cout << a;
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

```
Outputs
00000000
```

В этом случае просто создастся участок в памяти в функции foo, но указатель из main не будет на этот участок указывать и как следствие - утечка памяти.
В то время как в этой версии кода

```cpp
void foo(int *p) {
    delete p;
    p = new int(643);
}

int main() {
    int *a = new int(3);
    foo(a);
    cout << a;
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

Всё будет окей и утечек не будет, но мне нужно, чтоб функция foo была способна выделить память в указателе в main даже если он ссылается на nullptr. И вот такое решение мне не подходит по некоторым причинам. Так же использовать обёртки для указателя по типу share_ptr я тоже не могу, так как ограничен в библиотеках, и следовательно передать ссылку на объект с указателям нет возможности.

```
int* foo(int *p) {
    delete p;
    p = new int(643);
    return p;
}

int main() {
    int *a = nullptr;
    a = foo(a);
    cout << a;
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

Это не подходит ^

P.S Причина в том, что я делаю рекурсивый метод вставки элемента в бинарное дерево, а там такой фокус не подходит.

Comment: Во второй версии кода имеет место точно такая же утечка, как и в первой. Только еще добавляется неопределенное поведение из-за попытки повторного удаления. Третий вариант вполне рабочий, из-за чего вдруг он может не подходить - неясно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первый вариант - по ссылке, второй - указатель...

```
void foo(int* &p) {
    delete p;
    p = new int(643);
}

void foo(int **p) {
    delete *p;
    *p = new int(643);
}
```

В первом случае вызов, как и ранее, во втором -

```
int *a;
...
foo(&a);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Не додумался бы использовать указатель на указатель.

Comment: Ну, если ответ вас устроил - принимайте ("птичка" слева).